# Keep property in memory forever

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) library to my app, and there is what we can read in doc:

```
//declare this property where it won't go out of scope relative to your listener
let reachability = try! Reachability()
```

So, what I did is:

Create Singleton object to do stuff:

```
class ReachabilityService {
  static let shared = ReachabilityService()
  private init() {}
  private let reachability = try! Reachability()
}
```

Did add property to AppDelegate to keep it in memory for application life:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  let reachability = ReachabilityService.shared
}
```

My question is, will reachability property in AppDelegate be in memory for all of application lifetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the property declared in AppDelegate will be available throughout the lifecycle of the application.